# Why does the following Count down timer in android always shows 00:01 at the end?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-timer

```
String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
```

I seriously don't get

1) How minutes - hours work `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished))`

2) Why does it always ends with **00:01**?

3) How does `onTick()` method of `CountDowntimer` gets called?

Comment: use `DateUtils.formatElapsedTime` there is no need to reinent the wheel

Comment: @pskink DateUtils.formatElapsedTime is only for formatting time, right? or also to do the countDownTimer job?

Comment: `Formats an elapsed time in a format like "MM:SS" or "H:MM:SS" (using a form suited to the current locale), similar to that used on the call-in-progress screen.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) How minutes - hours work TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished))

- Don't know why you did this. You can just write

  String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d",
                      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));

2) Why does it always ends with 00:01?

Yes you are right! In the countdown timer last call will not trigger the onTick() method it will call the below method.

```
 public void onFinish() {
    mTextField.setText("00:00");
}
```

So you can set "00:00" at the onFinish() method shown in the above snippet.

3) How does onTick() method of CountDowntimer gets called?

-onTick() Callback fired on regular interval provided to the CountDowntimer constructor.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please answer my other two questions as well?